# Ctrl + V paste UTF-8 string from Clipboard to MS WORD result in ??? characters

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, unicode, clipboard, c#

I've develop application on Windows form [C#], then copy text using

```cs
System.Windows.Form.Clipboard.SetText("โปรแกรม Microsoft Word ใช้งานได้");
```

After sending **keybd_event** "Ctrl+V" [user32.dll]. I randomly found "???" Text issue like this post.

[Unicode characters being replaced by question marks after copy and paste on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1166350/unicode-characters-being-replaced-by-question-marks-after-copy-and-paste-on-wind?newreg=68fe1d40204343ae895a61916715664c)

This "???" problem randomly occurs in MS Word application, but placing text in Notepad and https://regex101.com/ work fine.

Example :

> โปรแกรม Microsoft Word ใช้งานได้ => ??????? Microsoft Word ?????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated 17/8/2020 :**

With Free Clipboard Viewer 3.0's help for debugging, I have discovered

Maybe target application auto detects it as Text or OEM Text which is in ??? format.
To prevent it, I use these lines of code.

```
DataObject dataObject = new DataObject(DataFormats.UnicodeText, text);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject);
```

As passing DataObject instead of string, It will tends to generate Clipboard object, which is Text, OEM Text and Unicode Text are in readable text format for non-English languages.

problem solved. maybe.